# Should a game specify the order in which randomized cards are drawn?

Tags: probability

I was playing a game where at certain points each player is instructed to draw a card (the cards are unique) from a shuffled deck into their hidden hands. No actions take place between draws. The game specifies an order for the players to draw the cards. This seems like a superfluous rule to me since the cards are randomized anyway. But obviously the order of the draws does change the outcome. Is there a principle I can point to that shows whether or not such an “order of draw” rule makes any sense?

(Obviously this is in terms of probability - for decorum's sake it very well may make sense to have a prescribed order of draw.)

Comment: If any game mechanics care about the order cards were drawn (such as doing something special with the first card drawn), this would make a difference.

Comment: Does something special happen when the deck runs out? That's often an edge case that makes the order matter if there are not sufficiently many cards left. (There are definitely concrete examples, such as in Dominion, where drawing order after certain actions is very precisely specified, but often only matters if a pile of cards runs out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independently of the order of play, assuming a shuffled deck, the probability of each player getting a certain card on the deck when they draw will be the same: $\frac1N$, where $N$ is the number of cards. Since you also specify that nothing happens between draws that could alter our chances, no, the order of play has no effect in theoretical terms.

The rule is probably in place just to avoid the players making a mess every time they need to draw.